Is it possible to use private IP to access Internet?
I just used my university’s WiFi and visited some websites that they allow. Inside one of their web, there's a line that reveals what IP address that I'm using to access that website. Then I realized that the IP address I'm using is 10.*.*.* --which is obviously a private IP address!
When I disconnected from the WiFi and use another WiFi, the IP changed to the public ones, and somehow I can't access some of their contents.
How is that possible? And how can I do so with my home network? I need to access some of their contents without going to the university. All they need is to verify that I'm using the IP address that they already listed… The private ones.

If you want to access their contents, then you'll need a VPN which will connect you to your Uni's N/W. Talk to your IT Admin guy, if your Uni's N/W has got a VPN, and you are authorized to get access to it, only then you'll be able to access your Uni's privately hosted sites and contents.

I see, I'll consider that. Thanks!

A device cannot access WAN with an RFC1918 IP, as not only would there be no route for traffic to go, end users have no control over the ISP's modem's IP - that's assigned by the ISP and modems literally speak an entirely different communication language than router's do - it's why they can only communicate over a modem's ethernet port and why even when ISP's have modem + router combos, AFAIK, the modem hardware is kept completely isolated from the router's (cli communication with modems is wonky and not at all like cli communication with a router)


Inside one of their web, there's a line that reveals what IP address that I'm using to access that website. Then I realized that the IP address I'm using is 10...* --which is obviously a private IP address!

The university network has a more direct connection to the website not through the Internet.
You cannot use private addresses on the Internet, but you can do the opposite – reach "public" addresses through other means than the Internet. For example, the website could even be on the same local network, in the university's local datacenter.
It might also be that there is a dedicated private connection set up for that purpose between the university and whoever hosts that site (either as a "site-to-site VPN" or an actual leased connection).

And how can I do so with my home network?

You cannot do that all by yourself. If you just try to send packets from a private address through the Internet, nothing will get back to you, as the Internet does not have routes for private addresses (which is what makes them "private addresses"). Unlike e.g. phone calls, connections over IP aren't actual circuits; they don't automatically know the way back to the client.
Normally this would be achieved by connecting to the university's network using a VPN (and most places provide one, often for that exact purpose of accessing internal resources).

like what if I connected to a remote device that is connected to that wifi? I know that sounds weird... Does that possible?

That's literally how "university VPN" works. (Or any other VPN, for that matter – the purpose of a VPN is just to connect you to some remote network.)
In theory it should be possible with any device on the university network, either by setting up a VPN service on it, or a proxy service, or just SSH (an SSH connection can be used as a kind of proxy) – but then you need some way to connect to that device first, and most likely you won't be able to reach it from outside.
This is possible to set up (although your university's network admins likely won't appreciate it), e.g. by having the device connect out to something else (e.g. a server on the Internet as the "meeting point"), or by having a second Internet connection (such as an LTE modem), but generally needs a bit of work.

Aah, God bless you man! I get the idea now. The "meeting point" is exactly what I need now! That's good to know, thanks man.
